# How to navigate a different PhoneApplicationPage?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm doing an application on Windows Phone and I don't know how to navigate other PhoneApplicationPage. Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you try some training - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/WindowsPhoneTrainingCourse

If you really want to learn the hard way, then here's a navigation tutorial - http://geekswithblogs.net/PeterTweed/archive/2010/05/17/simple-navigation-in-windows-mobile-7.aspx